# Create longform table from yearly frequencies in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame that I'm trying to prepare to run logistic regressions, turning the 'total' and 'yes' counts into a binary, where yes = yes and no = total-yes. Here's the original:

```
year<-1999:2012
total<-c(4372, 6448, 6141, 5630, 6588, 7878, 7768, 7352, 6333, 5168, 4569, 4152, 3540, 1412)
yes<-c(400, 580, 609, 567, 606, 843, 853, 839, 825, 607, 510, 459, 476, 209)
mdr<-data.frame(year, total, yes)
```

I want a longform table setting up binary yes/no with year as a linear variable; i.e. two columns: data$year, repeated 'total' times, and data$mdr, which is 'Y' repeated 'yes' times per year and 'N' repeated total-yes times that occur in a given year. Intuitively, and I know the syntax is awful here:

```
newdf<- 

for 1:i in mdr

newdf$year<-rep(year, 'total' times)
newdf$mdr<-rep(c('Y','N') times = c(yes, total-yes)
```

Expected output:

```
Year    MDR
1999     Y
1999     Y
1999     Y
1999     Y
```

But with 400 Y's and 4372-400 N's for 1999, 580 Y's and 6448-580 N's for 2000, etc.

Can someone help me turn that into a working loop or sapply or similar?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: You don't *need* to do this for logistic regression. See the description of `weights` in the Details of `?glm`. If you define `mdr$prop = mdr$yes / mdr$total` you can do `glm(prop ~ year, family = binomial, weights = total, data = mdf)`.

Comment: @Gregor, thanks!!! Saved me tons of work...have to iterate this over ~30 regressions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work to produce such a data.frame:

```
repVec <- c(t(cbind(mdr$yes, mdr$total-mdr$yes)))
df <- with(mdr, data.frame("year"=rep(year, total), 
                           "mdr"=rep(rep(c("y", "n"), nrow(mdr)), repVec)))
```

The first line creates a vector that has the appropriate number of yes's and no's for each year.

The `data.frame` function creates a data.frame, with year being repeated the proper number of times using `rep`. The mdr variable is constructed with two `rep` functions the first repeats c("y", "n") by the number of rows in your original data.frame. This vector is then fed to the the second rep function which repeats each element of this vector the number of times indicated by repVec.